# How can I prevent automatic image rotation?

Tags: jasper-reports

In Jasper report when the size of the image is huge it rotates the image automatically. How can I prevent that?

[image]

- First picture: 3024x3024 px 2MB
- Second picture: 1125x1500 px 300KB

Comment: it is related to the original image orientation  when they are originally taken ,not the size of the images .

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the Scale Image property. Try to change it to Retain Shape

Comment: no it is on the retain shape , also I have checked the other ones too .